# What is this schematic symbol that looks like a square with a slit halfway through it?

Tags: schematics, kicad, symbol

I have this schematic here I'm trying to recreate in Kicad. I'm lost on the meaning of part "PH_A, P8".

[image]

Comment: Pin 8 of a PH_A connector.

Comment: A pin connector for phase A.

Comment: I'd say a single-pin connector with a reference designator of P8.  PH_A is the name of the signal on that pin.  There is also a P9, with a signal name of PH_B

Comment: Phase A,.......

Answer (score 1):

As you might know in KiCAD the schematic symbols and the footprints are not coupled.

In order to recreate it use "conn_01x01" symbol in the schmatic editor(Eeschema). You can change its value to "PH_A". This symbol represents a single pin component, but it can be anything you want. You should refer to the pcb file of the attached project and search for "PH_A".